# Problems with configuration of Bluemix server

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to increase timeouts in Bluemix. I've set all the timeout settings to 5 min. But after 2 min of a request I got an error:

> 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This particular message probably comes from the L1 load balancer in Bluemix when it fails to get a timely response from the application it tries to route to. One of the possible cause here is because your application does not send any response back before the load balancer times out, which is 2 minutes if my memory serves me well."

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/25439/bluemix-500-error-failed-to-establish-a-backside-connection-on-web-service-call.html

I would open up a support ticket if you need any additional help.

Comment: How I can increase timeout of the L1 load balancer in Bluemix? Is it possible?

Comment: I think you will need to open up a support ticket to ask them if it's possible to achieve the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, and we can update the answer if necessary.